# new ubuntu 14.04 disk will not load

Tags: 14.04

I am new to ubuntu.

I purchased (donation) a CD from Canonical in March 2015.
The first time I inserted disk in drive and turned on laptop I got an error msg something like "no boot ???? found"  I didn't write it down and could not remember msg.

Laptop is Fuji-Siemens Amilo Li 1705 with Intel(R) Celeron(R) M cpu  440 @1.86GHz and 1.75GB RAM.
I am running Windows Vista

Now, when I try to boot with the ubuntu cd laptop tries to read it for about 1 minute and then stops and Windows boots.

If I put CD in while Windows is running, laptop seems to be reading disk for about 1 min and then ejects CD and error msg asks me to insert disk.

Can anyone help please, or should I just ask Canonical 
for another CD?

Answer (score 1):

You should first verify your boot bios settings to be sure you can boot from your CD Drive.

If the problem persists, try to launch from another CD in your drive to check your hardware integrity.

Otherwise, you can also install Ubuntu with Flash USB drive. You can find a tutorial at this link: [Create Bootable USB for Ubuntu from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is how your computer should work with the live CD:

If the disc is inserted before booting, it will launch Ubuntu. When inserting the disc after startup, it will autolaunch the wubi program, for restarting into Ubuntu. Upon startup you will have the option of trying or installing Ubuntu.

Edit: If not, then your CD appears to be defective. You could also burn Ubuntu to a DVD. Click on the link for a tutorial.

[Burning the Ubuntu ISO on to a DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Verifying_the_ISO_integrity)